# Flutter - PinCodeTextField doesn't trigger onSubmitted on enter button on webapp

Tags: flutter

PinCodeTextField(
autoFocus: true,
textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
onSubmitted: (value) {
print('Submitted called!');

```
                        },
                        appContext: context,
                        length: 6,
                        pastedTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green.shade600,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        pinTheme: PinTheme(
                            shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                            fieldHeight: 50,
                            fieldWidth: 40,
                            activeFillColor: Colors.white,
                            inactiveFillColor: Colors.white,
                            selectedFillColor: Colors.white,
                            inactiveColor: Colors.blue),
                        cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                        animationDuration:
                            const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        enableActiveFill: true,
                        onCompleted: (value) => enteredOTP = value,
                        showCursor: true,
                        beforeTextPaste: (text) {
                         
                          return true;
                        },
                      ),
```

I have added the onSubmitted property but it didnt work

Comment: PinCodeTextField(
                            autoFocus: true,
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                            onSubmitted: (value) {
                              print('ON subb');
                              int otp = int.parse(enteredOTP);

                              BlocProvider.of<VerifyOtpBloc>(context).add(
                                  VerifyOTPEvent(context, widget.phnNo, otp));
                            },